# Mixing Problem, Different Flow Rates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a double question and the first part reads

Consider a tank holding 100 gallons of water in which are dissolved 50 pounds of salt. Suppose that 2 gallons of brine, each containing 3 pounds of dissolved salt, run into the tank per minute, and the mixture(kept uniform by stirring) runs out of the tank at the rate of 2 gallons per minute, Let $A(t)$ be the amount of salt in the tank after $t$ minutes.

a) Set up the DE for the function $A(t)\\$
b) Solve this DE (finding the values of all parameters) for $A(t)\\$

Now the second part...

Suppose that, in the previous problem, 3 gallons of brine, each containing 1 pound of salt, run into the tank each minute - and all other facts are the same.

a) Set up the DE for the function $A(t)\\$
b) Solve this DE (finding the values of all parameters) for $A(t)\\$.

I have made it to part b) of the second part of the questions but I am unsure if my value of $C$ is correct. Any advice suggesting I am on the right path or otherwise is greatly appreciated. 
Note I must use the integrating factor to solve.

Here is where I am at:

2nd Question part b)...Solve this DE (finding the values of parameters) for $A(t)$

$\frac{dV}{dt} = 1 \implies \int{dV}=\int{dt} \implies v=t+c, v(t)=t+c\\v(0)=0+c set = 100\implies c=100$ 
$Update:V(t)=t+100\\$

Now update$\frac{dA}{dt}:\frac{dA}{dt}=3-\frac{2A}{t+100}\implies \frac{dA}{dt}+\frac{2A}{t+100}=3\\$

$\mu(t)=e^{\int{\frac{2}{t+100}}dt}=...(t+100)^3\\$

$\\(t+100)^2A=t^3+300t^2+30000+C\\$

$A=\frac{t^3+300t+30,000+C}{(t+100)^2}\\$

Applying Initial Condition: $A(0)=\frac{(0)^2+300(0)+30,000+C}{((0)+100)^2} set = 50\\$

$C=20,000$...?

Then $A(t)=\frac{t^3+300^t+50,000}{(t+100)^2}$....?

Again, I am just seeking to see if I am on the right track...

Comment: I think I found my error. After I integrated, it should be $30,000t$ not $30,000$ which then gives me a $C=50,000$ The rest I can figure out...and $A(t)=\frac{t^3+300t+30,000t+50,000}{(t+100)^2}$...can anyone else concur?